# Symlink a django template returns an error despite chmod 777

Tags: django, symlink

**Setup**

I have django working and serving pages nicely on my redhat box.

There's the following function which will serve the page "test.html" from a template directory:

```
def whatever_page(request):
    c = some_dictionary_with_some_data
    return render_to_response('test.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This works perfectly.

**Error**

However, when I go into the template directory and change `test.html` to a symlink of `/path/to/file/test.html`:

```
ln -s /path/to/file/test.html test.html
```

Reload the page in the browser and I get a `TemplateDoesNotExist` error.

**What I've tried so far**

- I tried `chmod 777` in case it was a permissions thing but that didn't work.
- The linked file definitely exists too as I can do `vim test.html` and it edits OK.
- I've done `service httpd restart` multiple times
- I tried stepping through it in the console and it works fine:

> ```
> [root@14:46:14 static]# ../myproject/manage.py shell
> Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 28 2012, 18:33:11)
> [GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> (InteractiveConsole)
> >>> from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
> >>> render_to_response("test.html", {})
> <django.http.HttpResponse object at 0x1274c10>
> ```

Any ideas why it wouldn't like a symlinked file?

Comment: (Not an answer, but) stepping into the `render_to_response` call with a [debugger](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb/) ought to lead you to a solution, it’s probably something subtle in the [template loaders](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/template/loaders).

Comment: I'll give that a shot and report back

Comment: Nope, it seems to work ok in the console for some reason (see above)

Comment: Tried this on my local debian system and it worked fine. I use the default loaders in django 1.6, filesystem.Loader and app_directories.Loader. As I use to store my templates within the apps the app_directories.Loader is the one who finds them. Perhaps you've got another setup with another loader which may have problems with symlinks?